# How to Replicate the mentioned Logic in Azure Data flow using Window function

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

**I have input table like**[image]

**My requirement is to fetch the behind One row value from current row if the current row value is null .Iam doing this by mentioning** [image]

In Sort ,am giving a surrogate key from 1 . This is giving me like the following :[image]

**BUT I need The Above output**
:[image]

**So the window function should look my behind row in real time not from the existing Column like** [image]

[image]

[image]

****I can achieve this by using**  **windows column: year = coalesce(year, last(year, true()))** But ,this is not feasible if I want to look behind >=2 Rows OR look Following >=2 rows .Can anyone suggest how to achieve this .**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of conditional split transformation, window functions and join to get the desired result. Lets stay I have the starting data as shown below:

```
year,month,product,sales,dummy,sk
2012,1,p1,100,1,1
2012,2,p2,200,1,2
,3,p3,300,1,3
,4,p4,400,1,4
,5,p5,500,1,5
,6,p6,600,1,6
,7,p7,700,1,7
,8,p8,800,1,8
,9,p9,900,1,9
,10,p10,1000,1,10
,11,p11,1100,1,11
,12,p12,1200,1,12
2013,1,q1,100,1,13
2013,2,q2,200,1,14
,3,q3,300,1,15
,4,q4,400,1,16
,5,q5,500,1,17
,6,q6,600,1,18
,7,q7,700,1,19
,8,q8,800,1,20
,9,q9,900,1,21
,10,q10,1000,1,22
,11,q11,1100,1,23
,12,q12,1200,1,24
```

[image]

- Now, I have applied transformations as shown in the below dataflow JSON to get the desired results:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow2",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                },
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source2"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "split1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "window1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "join1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          year as short,",
                "          month as short,",
                "          product as string,",
                "          sales as short,",
                "          dummy as boolean,",
                "          sk as short",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source(output(",
                "          year as short,",
                "          month as short,",
                "          product as string,",
                "          sales as short,",
                "          dummy as boolean,",
                "          sk as short",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source2",
                "source1 split(not(isNull(year)),",
                "     disjoint: false) ~> split1@(notNulls, nulls)",
                "split1@notNulls window(over(dummy),",
                "     asc(sk, true),",
                "     new_rn = lead(sk,1,9999)) ~> window1",
                "source2, window1 join(source2@sk >= split1@notNulls@sk",
                "     && source2@sk <= minus(new_rn,1),",
                "     joinType:'inner',",
                "     matchType:'exact',",
                "     ignoreSpaces: false,",
                "     broadcast: 'left')~> join1",
                "join1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          month = source2@month,",
                "          product = source2@product,",
                "          sales = source2@sales,",
                "          year = split1@notNulls@year",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['output.csv'],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- Here, both source1 and source2 use the same dataset i.e., the file data given above. The final output after applying these transformations is as shown below:

```
"month","product","sales","year"
"1","p1","100","2012"
"2","p2","200","2012"
"3","p3","300","2012"
"4","p4","400","2012"
"5","p5","500","2012"
"6","p6","600","2012"
"7","p7","700","2012"
"8","p8","800","2012"
"9","p9","900","2012"
"10","p10","1000","2012"
"11","p11","1100","2012"
"12","p12","1200","2012"
"1","q1","100","2013"
"2","q2","200","2013"
"3","q3","300","2013"
"4","q4","400","2013"
"5","q5","500","2013"
"6","q6","600","2013"
"7","q7","700","2013"
"8","q8","800","2013"
"9","q9","900","2013"
"10","q10","1000","2013"
"11","q11","1100","2013"
"12","q12","1200","2013"
```

[image]

**Flow images:**

- Source1:

[image]

- Source2 (same as source1):

[image]

- Conditional split (split1):

[image]

- Window1 (over : dummy, sort ascending : sk , range : unbounded):

[image]

- Join1:

[image]

- Select1:

[image]

- Sink1 (data):

[image]

Comment: Can you present it in UI  Please  . importing this json giving some error in my adf .

Comment: Hey @AzSuryaTeja, save the data from 3rd image in the question into a csv file and continue with the above solution.

Comment: Actually importing that dataflow code into git hub and loading it up in datafactory giving me some json errors , Thats why I asked Can you represent it in Screenshots

Comment: Hey @AzSuryaTeja, I have added images for each of the flow transformation. Consider checking it.

Comment: But why you have given 9999 in lead ,if my no of rows is 1 million ,this fails right

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can change this number according to the number of rows that you have. However, I have not tested it for huge number of rows.

Comment: As no of rows is so dynamic in real time . we can produce a count but ,i think this is not efficient for large datasets.

Comment: Did you get anything on this ?